# Is any other quickest to print the same result?

Tags: ruby

Code:

```
arr = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
a=0
b=0
while b <= 2
    a=0
    while a <= 2
    print arr[a][b]
    a+=1
    end
b+=1
puts " "
end
```

Output:

```
147
258
369
```

Is there a quicker way of achieving the same result?

I am just a beginner, so don't make it too had.

Comment: Since you said you're a beginner, it's the Ruby way to almost always avoid for and while loops in your code.  You'll find yourself wishing other languages had `each` and `times` after using Ruby for a while.  Cheers :)

Comment: `while` is useful, but not in this way. `for` is almost always useless. The Ruby way is to use internal iterators and avoid external iterators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `puts` for each line.

```
arr.transpose.each{|l| puts "#{l.join} "}
```

would give the same result as you did, but perhaps you wanted

```
arr.transpose.each{|l| puts l.join}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using [`#join`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-join) method:

```
print arr.transpose.map { |a| a.join('') }.join(' ')
```

or if each value should be in different line, then you can write

```
puts arr.transpose.map { |a| a.join('') }
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
arr = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
puts arr.transpose.map(&:join).join(' ')
# => 147 258 369
```

Comment: Do not use `#join` without params. It is considered as bad idea.

Comment: @ŁukaszNiemier Why? I disagree.

Comment: As somewhere, somebody can change `$,` and your function will return something strange.

Comment: @ŁukaszNiemier Nice warning you have put here. *+1*.